# Detect when user switches tabs / hides window

Tags: video

I'm developping a fitness learning course with a learning management system.

For complete a lesson, the user must to see the entire video. (the mark complete button appears after the coutdown is complete).

However it's possible for an user to play the video ,and leave the page (but still keep the page open) by opening a new tab.

In some advertising, I know that when I leave a page, the advetising stop when I leave the page, and play when I come back, so the brand is sure that I seen the advertising

I want to know, if youtube (even pro version) have a solution for this ?

If not, I want to know in what way I must to search, what function in the API by example ?
Thanks for the help !

Raphael

Comment: I think your question could use a more relevant title. For instance; "Detect when user switches tabs / hides window"

Comment: @Katana314 [Go for it!](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22789215/edit)

Comment: Find !

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API